# Conversion of third party eclipse plug-in to netbeans IDE compatible plugins/modules

Tags: eclipse, plugins

HI Folks,

Can any one there confirm if we can convert third party eclipse plug-in to netbeans IDE compatible plugins/modules.

As far as I know, there is a way if I am a plugin developer instead. 
http://wiki.netbeans.org/EclipsePluginToNetBeansModuleMigrationCookbook

In this case, I am just a consumer of a third-party eclipse plugin.
http://www.fosstrak.org/llrp/download.html

Problem is, as my team is adapted to Netbeans I cant go and say just to use this plugin, install eclipse ( Alaaaaaaaas!!!!!!!)

Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no netbeans hosting of eclipse plugins.  You have to convert it to a netbeans plugin, since netbeans uses AWT/Swing and eclipse uses SWT/Jface.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/EclipsePluginToNetBeansModuleMigrationCookbook (which you already found)
http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/How-to-integrate-an-eclipse-plugin-to-netbeans-td3425777.html